# How to fix java EOFException using ObjectInbputStreem in java network

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I want to send some objects using network. My network I made it using `DatagramSocket`, `DatagramPacket`, `ByteArrayInputStream`, `ObjectInputStream`, `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.
When I was trying to send an object using network I got `java.io.EOFException` and when I handled this exception using `try and catch` I lost my object.

Server Side

```
public class GameServer extends Thread {
private DatagramSocket socket;
private DatagramPacket packet;
private byte[] data;
private ByteArrayInputStream bais;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private Game game;

public GameServer() {
    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket(1331);
    }
    catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        data = new byte[6400];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        Object object = receive();

        if (object instanceof String) {
            String message = (String) object;
            System.out.println("CLIENT [ " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " : " + packet.getPort() + " ] >> " + message.trim());
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
                game = new Game("Tankies", 1200, 700);
                sendObject(game);
            }
        }
        else if (object instanceof State) {
            System.out.println("got state");
        }
        else if (object instanceof Player)
            System.out.println("hi player");

    }
}

private Object receive() {
    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(bais));
        return ois.readObject();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("SERVER Got EOFException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private void sendData(byte[] data, InetAddress ipAddress, int port) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, port);
    try {
        this.socket.send(packet);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendObject(Object object) {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(6400);
    oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendData(baos.toByteArray(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
}
```

}

Client Side

```
public class GameClient extends Thread implements Serializable {

private InetAddress ipAddress;
private transient DatagramSocket socket;
private transient DatagramPacket packet;
private byte[] data;
private transient ByteArrayInputStream bais;
private transient ObjectInputStream ois;
private transient ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
private transient ObjectOutputStream oos;
private Game game;


public GameClient(String ipAddress) {
    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
    }
    catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        this.ipAddress = Inet4Address.getByName(ipAddress);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        data = new byte[6400];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        Object object = receive();

        if (object instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("SERVER >> " + object);
        }
        else if (object instanceof Game) {
            this.game = (Game) object;
            this.game.setClient(this);
            this.game.start();
        }

    }
}

private Object receive() {
    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(bais));
        return ois.readObject();
    }
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private void sendData(byte[] data) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, 1331);
    try {
        this.socket.send(packet);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendObject(Object object) {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(6400);
    oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendData(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

}

Code to send the object to server

```
public class MultiplayerState extends State{
private World world;
private Tank myTank, playerTank;

public MultiplayerState(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

@Override
public void startState() {
    world = new World(handler,"res/worlds/world1.txt");
    handler.setWorld(world);
    myTank = new Tank(handler, world.getSpawnX(), world.getSpawnY());
    handler.getGame().getRender().addObject(world);
    handler.getGame().getRender().addObject(myTank);
    world.start();
    myTank.start();
    handler.getGame().getClient().sendObject(handler.getGame().getPlayer());
}
```

}

```
handler.getGame().getClient().sendObject(handler.getGame().getPlayer());
```

This line to send `player` to server .. some explanation about code .. this is a game using multithreading in java and i want to create simple network to make two different laptops playing this game online because of that i made this network. I created class `Handler` this is a class to manage all the game, using object instance of `Handler` class I can get anything in the game and I want to get object instance of `Player` class to send it to server because I want to do something to make the game online.

Comment: That exception means the stream was incomplete. 6400 bytes may not be enough for what you're sending. Try tracing the sent and received lengths. Datagrams larger than the buffer you provide are truncated.

Comment: I made it 20000 and its still give me same exception

Comment: For the same reason. What sizes did you observe when you followed my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exception by made `GameClient` object in `Game` class `transient` because I don't want to serialize it. What I want is to use this object to send something to server from `Game` object internally.

Comment: So you made it smaller, so it fitted your buffer.